# What is the difference between DatagramSocket & DatagramChannel?

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, nio

I'm trying to build a conference call application over Wifi Direct. I got success in establishing one-one connection between two android devices using Normal Socket on Android. As my requirement is to build a conference calling application I need RTP(UDP Based) so I'm trying out this DatagramSocket that works on top of connectionless UDP. Now I'm confused between using DatagramSocket & DatagramChannel.

Comment: Unless you know you need non-blocking or multiplexed I/O you don't need DatagramChannel. Stick to what you have.

Comment: Should I use non-blocking IO for that conference thing?

Comment: I don't see why. The choice has to do with the proposed structure of your program, not with the external problem you're trying to solve.